# Dynamic html email with dropdown

Tags: python, html, dynamic, jinja2, dropdown

I am trying to generate html email, that would show data based on dropdown menu selection within email. I have been looking around and could not find anything suitable for this use case.

Currently my procedure is that I use `Python` to generate all required data and than render html template with `Jinja2` package.
What I would like to have is first part of email to be static and than under that section have a dropdown menu, which would render rest of email based on selection. I wonder if that is even possible (on side note, I can not use JS, as it is blocked for mails that are generated)?

Thank you and best regards,
Bostjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to work with css's :active property to work around js here.

Your problem will be the broad variety of email programms, outlook and such will fail to process this correctly.

Comment: Hello Marvin, thank you for reply. As target program is basically Outlook, this won't work than. I will just have to change structure of email than.